# Django: Using a For Loop in a DetailView class page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Using Django, is it possible to have a For Loop in a page from a DetailView Class page?

I have detail pages of things pulled from my database, but I was hoping I could have a For Loop inside that page that runs through a list of names in that table to link to each other (if that makes sense).

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import payplan_emails_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('normal-payplan-emails/<int:pk>', payplan_emails_view.as_view(), name="normal-payplan-emails"),
]
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import knowledgebase_instruction
from django.views.generic import DetailView


class payplan_emails_view(DetailView):
    model = knowledgebase_instruction
    template_name = "instructions/payplans_base.html"
```

**payplans_base.html:**

```
{% block content %}

<h4>{{knowledgebase_instruction.name}}</h4>
<p>{{knowledgebase_instruction.instructions|safe}}</p>
              
<ul>

  <!-- I would love to loop through items in the table here -->
  
  <li><a href="#">List Item 1</a></li>
</ul>

{% endblock%}
```

Comment: I think you can't use `for loop` in **DetailView** because it returns a single object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went a different route with it.

Instead of using the generic DetailView. I just made a new function in views and queried the database in that, passing in the pk from the URL.

Works good now.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for o in some_list %}
    <tr>
       {{ o }}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

For details, please refer to this：[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle)

Answer (score 0):

**If i understand you question you have to make new class ListView and just put it in the same template.**

**VIEWS:**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class list_name(ListView):
  model = model_in_what_are_users_stored
  template_name = "instructions/payplans_base.html"
```

**TEMPLATE:**

```
{% for model_in_what_are_users_stored in model_in_what_are_users_storeds %}
{ model_in_what_are_users_stored.user }
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I would need to register a new URL for that in the urls.py then, right? I don't think (or at least, I don't know how to, lol) I can have one page that has two views... so you are on the detail page viewing a specific primary key, while looping through the ListView view on the same page.